# Should you commit rc and other config files

Tags: git, github, config

I'm wondering whether or not you should commit rc files such as `.prettierrc` or `.firebaserc` and other config files such as `.editorconfig` to GitHub or not?

Comment: Opinionated question. I would suggest that you do. Those are useful settings when working in teams, you want all member using same coding guidelines. Avoid only sensitive data like passwords or alike

Comment: It depends.  If the files are specific to your project, then it is appropriate to commit them.  If they are appropriate for your work flow, then it is not.  Is `.editorconfig` a config file for your personal preferences in you editor?  If so, it should not be committed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should commit config files that are static and apply to the project as a whole, but not anything that contains credentials, varies per developer, or would need to be modified in place.

For example, committing an `.editorconfig` file or a file that works with your project's code formatting or linting tool is a good idea, since these set the style for your project and let all developers use a consistent set of formatting standards.

You should avoid committing files for a particular editor, since different developers use different editors, and likewise you should avoid committing any config file that contains a developer's signing certificate or user ID (of whatever kind).

If your program reads from a given config file on startup and that config file will need to be modified, you should not commit it in that location; instead, you should commit a template or sample next to it that can be modified as appropriate.

This helps each developer have the necessary tools and config files to write, lint, style, and run the project without having committed files that are irrelevant or must constantly be in a modified state.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic answer, but I think this kind of question warrants one.

Whenever you're deciding whether or not to commit a file, ask yourself, what does the file do?

A lot of hidden files (files that start with a `.`) are configuration files for a text editor, piece of software, or a framework. Sometimes they are essential to the program's function, sometimes not. Sometimes they are auto-generated when the software/editor/framework is invoked, sometimes not. Sometimes they need to be specific to each user's work environment (e.g. a `.config` file that has local database user and password info) sometimes not.

These are the questions you should ask when deciding whether or not to commit *any* file to origin. It differs with different scenarios.